# Pending intent activity result

Tags: android, android-intent, android-pendingintent

I'm starting a pending intent activity from a thread once the exception arises, how to handle the activity result

i.e once user open the notification and finishes the activity. How to get result

Here is my pending intent code

```
        PendingIntent pendingNotificationIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                        mContext, constants.REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION, e.getIntent(),
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
                        | PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
```

e is the intent, once user opens this and finishes all the steps how to get notification once he finishes

Comment: Your question is a bit chaotic.

Comment: Hi, i'm creating the notification with pending intent object as shown above. This i'm doing from a thread once exception arises. Now user click on notification, and he will authorize. I want to know how to get the activity for result once he closes the authorization activity

Answer (score 0):

You cannot "*get the activity for result*" because you are not calling `startActivityForResult()` in a first place. Also response from such activity goes back to `onActivityResult()` which is not part of your thread. If you need to communicate certain state change across your app, I'd i.e. extend `Application` object (or create separate class utilizing `Singleton` pattern) and then my authorization Activity would report status change back to Application object. Simpler approach would be to save authorization result in `SharedPreferences` so you can access it from other objects.

Comment: Hi, i'm getting UserRecoverableAuthIOException. so i'm using its intent only to create a authorization activity, is there a way we can get through broadcast receiver?

Comment: Are you using GoogleAPIS? http://javadoc.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/1.12.0-beta/com/google/api/client/googleapis/extensions/android/gms/auth/UserRecoverableAuthIOException.html

Comment: Yes, you can use broadcast. In general do whatever would work for you best when you finish with authorization.

Comment: See the docs I linked to see how to deal with `UserRecoverableAuthIOException`

Comment: But i'm not getting how to do that broadcast piece, i'm getting the notification, i'm getting authorization screen, but i' dont no how to get to know once the user finishes the authorization

Comment: Yes. i know how to handle if its done via Activity.startActivityForResult. But i'm launching this intent with help of pendingintnet. how to get the results once user authorizes i'm confused :(